# SamsungApps start Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, samsung-mobile

Actually I want some advice, how to start SamsungApps application from my android application and automatically redirect to my seller account. For example, when I want to start Market app, I just start Intent with "market://...." URI. Is there some similar mechanism to start SamsungApps? Or how at least start a browser with my seller account page?
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I googled a little better and found this snippet. Works for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();

// set data
intent.setData(Uri.parse(string_of_uri)); // The string_of_uri is a String object including a URI such as "samsungapps://ProductDetail/{the package name of the AndroidManifest.xml file in your application}".

// add flags
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
// The Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag must only be added if the API level of your Android SDK is above 11 like Honeycomb.

startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you tell me which intent opens samsung knox store.? @deviant

Comment: CHAKRAVARTHI, sorry, don't know what is it.

Comment: No issues.  Actually samsung knox store is available in samsung devices for secured apps.